# How to chain Scala Futures with timeouts?

Tags: scala, concurrency, timeout, future

Suppose I've got a few functions that return `Future`:

```
def fab(a: A, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[B] = ???
def fbc(b: B, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[C] = ???
def fcd(c: C, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[D] = ???
```

If `timeOutMillis > 0` the functions return futures that complete within `timeOutMillis` period of time. Otherwise they return a failed `Future`.

Now I want to compose these functions to write `fac` and `fad`:

```
def fac(a: A, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[C] = ???
def fad(a: A, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[D] = ???
```

So I can implement `fac` like this:

```
def fac(a: A, timeOutMillis: Long): Future[C] = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  for {
     b <- fab(a, timeOutMillis)
     timeAB = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
     c <- fbc(b, timeOutMillis - timeAB)
  } yield c
}
```

Note I don't want to *wait* for completion of futures, therefore I don't use `Await`.

This `fac` implementation will probably work but it looks clumsy and contains boilerplate code.
How would you suggest chain `Futures` with timeouts ?

P.S. I'm thinking about overriding `flatMap` of `Future` to calculate the next timeout. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for `scala.duration.Deadline`.

```
    d = timeoutMillis.millis.fromNow
    fab(a, d.timeLeft.toMillis)
      .flatMap(fbc(_, d.timeLeft.toMillis))
      .flatMap(fcd(_, d.timeLeft.toMillis))
```

If you don't like having to repeat the `d.timeTimeLeft.toMillis` mantra,
you can collapse it into a fold, and also generalize it for any number
of chained calls:

```
Seq(fab _, fbc _, fcd _)
  .foldLeft(Future(a)) { case (last, next) => 
     last.flatMap(next(_, d.timeLeft.toMillis))
   }
```

Comment: Great ! That's probably what I am looking for. `fold` with `Deadline` looks really nice :))

Comment: Now I wonder if it's possible to make passing the deadline _transparent_ for the client. That is, I would like to write just `for { b <- fab(a); c <- fbc(b) } yield c` without passing  `deadline.timeLeft` explicitly.

Comment: Well, I think, you'd have to modify the original function definitions to do that. `def fab(a: A)(implicit deadline: Deadline = 100.years.fromNow) = ???`

Comment: Yes, I can do it ... I guess I should also define a new class `FutureWithDeadline extends Future` and override `flatMap` to pass the deadline.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Personally, I have found that subclassing scala standard library classes is almost never worth the trouble. It is also not as simple as it looks. Your .flatMap would need to return your new class instance, so you won't be able to just call .`super`. You will also have to override `map` (and most other methods) for the same reason. Besides, the semantics of this new `flatMap` would be different (it'd have to only work with certain kind of functions) ...

Comment: I concur, the subclassing is complicated. Not sure how to make deadlines transparent for the client code though ... :((

Comment: Make the Deadline implicit?

Comment: Thanks, let's try it ! Suppose I make the deadline implicit for `fab` and `fbc` as @Dima suggested `def fab(a: A)(implicit deadline: Deadline): Future[B] = ???`. Now I can write `def fac(a: A)(implicit deadline: Deadline): Future[C] = for { b <- fab(a); c <- fbc(b) } yield c`. Would it work as expected ? I will check ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Await,Future}

Await.ready(fut1, 5.seconds).flatMap { sucInTime =>
  fut2
}
```

Comment: First of all I don't want to _wait_ for completion. Secondly, it does not seem to work as expected. I don't understand how the timeout for the 2nd future is calculated.

Comment: You need to be much more clearer on the need then.

Comment: You are right. I will clarify the question.